# Fade body background when text input has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple text input box in a form.  I would like the body background to have an overlay over it when the input box has focus.

What is the best way to approach this, jquery?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle or code snippet with what you have?

Comment: JavaScript or JQuery will work. JQuery is in essence, JavaScript.

Comment: What kind of overlay ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS `:focus` selector to do that.

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  opacity: .5;
  display: none;
}
#text {
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: relative;
}
#text:focus ~  #overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the `z-index` depending on the various elements on your page.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')
  text.onfocus = function() {
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
  };
  text.onblur = function() {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
  };
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  opacity: .5;
  display: none;
}
#text {
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Please let me know if I can improve this answer.